# Nest api multiple thermostat or smoke alarms

Tags: java, android, nest-api

Im working with nest API to build an Android app.

Im connecting multiple Thermostats to one nest account. Next, I add Thermostat listeners. I can print out everything i would like to about the thermostats (temp, label, target, etc) but i can not figure out how to dynamically respond only to a specific thermostat. Each thermostat gets an index number, but the order of index number is random. does anyone know how one would set the order of thermostats indexes?

for example, if thermostat in the living room is triggered, do something specific in the living room. but how would i know the corresponding index to each device?

Comment: Check the device name or the device_id since those probably won't change. The name might change if you rename the device.

Answer (score 0):

Like [joseph-evans](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4488318/joseph-evans) mentioned the `device_id` is static to you as a developer and wont change unless the devices is completely deleted from the Nest account and re-paired. Other developers will see a different ID, but for your sake you can always uniquely identify the device by its `device_id`